# Inconsistency when signed in with tow different credentials

Tags: android

I signed in into the app with some credentials and that user has some data that is downloaded through web service. The problem is that when I sign in using some other credentials after signing out(not exiting the application), sometimes I get the data of previous user. Can anyone tell what could be the problem. What can I do when I log out to delete the data related to previous  user.

Comment: How do you store the data to start with?

Comment: Simple in arraylists or hashmap that's it.

Comment: So just clear them. `ArrayList.clear();`

Comment: But then Y does this not happen when I quit the app.?

Comment: Because your hashmap is in volatile memory and when your activity is recreated your hashmap is reinstantiated as a new object (an empty object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is stored in an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) then when one user 'signed out' you can call the [clear()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear%28%29) method to clear your memory.

Similarly with [HashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html) it also has the [clear()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html#clear%28%29) method.

Comment: Do I need to do same for static variables also? or something different

Comment: Hey I tried this and it worked. I have a confusion should I use static variables here..? Because when I'm just clearing the static arrayList, it is not eligible for garbage collection, right? when I null that arrayList, the app crashes when i sign in using different credentials.

Comment: If your doing a 'cache' style list then static is a good idea although not necessary. It won't be garbaged collected because you need it! If you null it then it will GC but then you've lost your reference to it. Maybe look at 'lazy initialization' if you want to null it after use.